# XPath and fn:id

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm trying to run some XPath against an XML document and just select the element returned with a specific id. I am using the following:

```
id('some-value')
```

This works fine but I believe (correct me if I am wrong!) that the syntax of fn:id can be expanded so you can call

```
id('some-value', 'another-value')
```

which would return the elements that have the ids specified but I generate an error when calling the function like this. I am use the PHP DOM so it may be that the library doesn't accept this syntax.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Wierd one - Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid number of arguments - which is strange because all I am doing is passing the string with the xpath in it - i.e. only one argument - no errors if I pass id('some-value')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `id('some-value another-value')`.

I.e. a **space separated list** of id values as a single quoted argument.

Comment: Brilliant - exactly what I was looking for. Do you know any good resources for the syntax of xpath functions?

Comment: Personally, I read the W3C specs. Very comprehensive and authoritative but not always the most readable. I find http://www.w3viewer.com/ a good tool for navigating the specs. The various XPath versions are under the 'X' menu option.

Comment: I tried the specs too but you;re right they are a bit of a dry read! Will try w3viewer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tim Smith: shameless ad, but I think you would benefit from having a copy of "XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference" on your desk.